# Error on Updating Table in Sqlite

Tags: java, android, sqlite

When trying to update a record for one of my records I am using this code

```
    private void UpdateCattleRecord(UpdateCattleRecord updateRecord){
             mDB.beginTransaction();
             String where = "_ID=";
             String[] RecordToUpdate = {Cattle._ID};
             Toast.makeText(this,"Updating Animal "+ RecordToUpdate, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             try {
                    ContentValues CattleFieldsToUpdate = new ContentValues();
                    CattleFieldsToUpdate.put(Cattle.CATTLE_ANIMALID,updateRecord.getCattleName());
                    CattleFieldsToUpdate.put(Cattle.CATTLE_TYPE, updateRecord.getCattleType());
                    CattleFieldsToUpdate.put(Cattle.CATTLE_LOCATION, updateRecord.getCattleLocation());
                    CattleFieldsToUpdate.put(Cattle.CATTLE_DOB, updateRecord.getCattleDob());
                    CattleFieldsToUpdate.put(Cattle.CATTLE_DAM, updateRecord.getCattleDam());
                    CattleFieldsToUpdate.put(Cattle.CATTLE_SEX, updateRecord.getCattleSex());
                    mDB.update(Cattle.CATTLE_TABLE_NAME,CattleFieldsToUpdate, where, RecordToUpdate);
                    mDB.setTransactionSuccessful();
              } finally {
                 mDB.endTransaction();
             }
    }
```

My log shows

> Tag Database sqlite returned: error  code =1, msg = near "=": syntax error

After researching this, I think I have everything in the right place but obviously I don't,
when I look at the next error in the log it's of course in 'red' and it shows me all the correct data,

> 03-27 15:15:29.291: E/Database(12011): Error updating date_of_birth=March 27, 2012 animaltype=Calf sex=F location=Eastern dam=601 animal_id=601A using UPDATE cattle SET date_of_birth=?, animaltype=?, sex=?, location=?, dam=?, animal_id=? WHERE _ID=

I've obviously got a problem with the value for _ID but can't seem to locate it. Can someone please point out where my Syntax error is?

**Update**

The problem occurred because I was failing to pass the actual value of the record (_ID) that I wanted to update. Once I passed that as a parameter to my updaterecords function the update went as scheduled.

Thanks for the input, it helped me narrow down what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Check your database creation, your probably have a column named `_id`(although you refer to it by `_ID`, its name is `_id`) and not `_ID`:

```
String where = "_id= ?"; // ? represent the value from the selection arguments String array
```

or better:

```
String where = Cattle._ID + "= ?";
```

Edit:
In your where selection argument you put:

```
String[] RecordToUpdate = {Cattle._ID};
```

you probably want to put in there some id you get from somewhere(of the record you want to update, a `long` number), right now you're doing:

```
WHERE _ID = _ID (or _id)
```

and this will fail.

Comment: Slukian, I verified the spelling of the _ID and it's capitalized correctly in all cases.  It won't let me use anything but a string when I do the system gives me an x saying the syntax isn't correct, how would I assign a long to the value RecordtoUpdate?

Comment: @Hank Use `String where = Cattle._ID + "= ?";` for the `WHERE` clause and use `String[] RecordToUpdate = {"" + longValue};` for the where selection clause, (`longValue` is the id of the record to update).

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
 mDB.update(Cattle.CATTLE_TABLE_NAME,CattleFieldsToUpdate, "_ID="+Cattle._ID, null);
```

try:

```
mDB.update(Cattle.CATTLE_TABLE_NAME,CattleFieldsToUpdate, "_ID="+updateRecord.getId(), null);
```

Comment: Crossfire, using that syntax there was no error but it updated every record in the database (there's only two, so...)

Comment: you want to update the object UpdateCattleRecord updateRecord right? If so you have to set the WHERE clause to something like my second part of the answer.